# Unable to connect to your database server using the provided settings. (Codeigniter) and The MySQL® server is currently offline. (cPanel)

Tags: database, codeigniter, cpanel

From Last night my site giving me this error.

> A Database Error Occurred
>
> Unable to connect to your database server using the provided settings.
>
> Filename: core/Loader.php
>
> Line Number: 268

When I logged the error, I find these line in my log file

> ERROR - 2013-03-03 23:38:44 --> Severity: Warning  -->
>   mysql_pconnect() [function.mysql-pconnect]: Too many
>   connections
>   /home/myappbui/public_html/system/database/drivers/mysql/mysql_driver.php
>   88 ERROR - 2013-03-03 23:38:44 --> Unable to connect to the database

Then I went to cPanel where I clicked on **'MySql Databases'** its give me this error

> The MySQL® server is currently offline.

and when I clicked on **phpMyAdmin** it not logged in to my Database.
What can be the problem?

Comment: Just a thought... maybe the MySQL server/mysqld is... offline?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using MacOS you have to edit the php.ini file (/etc/php.ini) and change all occurrences of the location for the mysql.sock:

**From:** /var/mysql/mysql.sock **to:** /tmp/mysql.sock

Answer (score 0):

Your Database connection file giving this error

Your php request to mysql connection is refuse.

so there is possibility is your phpmyadmin server may be stop

so start your wamp or zamp server if server is started then restart all service

might be your problem is solve using above process.

Comment: the OP is not on localhost.

Comment: Yes my connection url is proper

Comment: @RohitR.K. I am not talking about localhost my site is live.